# Any better resource for learning Magento 2 API implementation?

Tags: api

If anybody know any better resource that can help me in understanding Magento2 API. please share.
It can be either any videos links, books, website links etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get better source than devdocs. Devdocs have a detailed explanation about each point.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

also, Magento Provide Swagger tool that help to which API end point is use for which functionality.

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_23.html

On top of that i am sharing with you link of video ,where you can understand more about WebAPI.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9t7SjJVbKA